# Highchart customized animation on setSeries or setCategories

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have created graph (highchart graph) where i have added 3 customized button example is here

http://jsfiddle.net/eszwd420/

```
 $(function () { 
 var averageLabel =[1278302400000, 1286251200000, 1294203600000, 1301976000000, 1309838400000, 1317787200000, 1325739600000, 1333598400000, 1341460800000, 1349409600000, 1357362000000, 1365134400000, 1372996800000, 1380945600000, 1388898000000, 1396670400000, 1404532800000, 1412481600000, 'THIS YR', 'NEXT YR'];
  var growthData   = [85.43, 76.12, 70.19, 66.77, 54.47, 67.33, 62.32, 53.71, 25.78, 7.55, -1.51, -9.32, -10.14, -3.76, 4.51, 9.36, 11.67, 24.12, '19.69##red', '23.45##red'];

  for(var i = 0; i < growthData.length; i++){
    if (typeof growthData[i] == 'string') {
        var valData = growthData[i].split('##');             
        var dtpoint = parseFloat(valData[0]);
        var dtcolor = valData[1];
      } else {
        var dtpoint = growthData[i];
        var dtcolor = "";
      }
      growthData[i] =  {//x: categories[i],
                     y:dtpoint,
                     color:dtcolor}
  }

  var chartY = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
      height: 400,
      renderTo: 'container',
      type: 'line',
      marginBottom: 100,
      marginTop: 100,
      marginLeft: 40,
      marginRight: 100,    

    },

    title: {
      text: "Growth Rate - Yearly",
      align: 'center',
      x: 10,
      y: 20,
      style: {
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      //max: ,
      categories: averageLabel,
      type: 'datetime',
      labels: {

               formatter: function () {
                  var s = "";
                  if (typeof this.value == 'string') {
                    s = this.value
                  };
                  if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.value) == 'Jan') {
                      s = Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y', this.value) + "-";
                      s = s + "Q1"
                  };
                  if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.value) == 'Apr') {
                      s = Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y', this.value) + "-";
                      s = s + "Q2"
                  };
                  if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.value) == 'Jul' ) {
                      s = Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y', this.value) + "-";
                      s = s + "Q3"
                  };  
                  if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.value) == 'Oct' ) {
                      s = Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y', this.value) + "-";
                      s = s + "Q4"
                  };
                  //s = Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y', this.value) + "-" + s;
                  return s;
              },
            rotation: -45,
        },
        //tickInterval: 3 * 30 * 24 * 3600 * 900,
    },
   tooltip: {
       formatter: function () {
            var s = '';
            if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.x) == 'Jan') {
                s = s + "Q1"
            };
            if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.x) == 'Apr') {
                s = s + "Q2"
            };
            if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.x) == 'Jul') {
                s = s + "Q3"
            };
            if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.x) == 'Oct') {
                s = s + "Q4"
            };

            if (typeof this.x == 'string') {
                s = this.x;
            }  else {
                s = Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y', this.x) + '-'+ s;
            }

            $.each(this.points, function (i, point) {
                s += '<br/>' + point.series.name + ': <b>';

                    s += Highcharts.numberFormat(point.y, 2, '.');
                    s += '%</b>';

            });
            return s;
        },
        shared: true,
        valueDecimals: 2,
        valueSuffix: ' %'
     },
    yAxis: {
       endOnTick: true,
        allowDecimals: false,
        min: -10.14,
        opposite: true,
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
              return this.value+'%';
            }
       },      
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
    },
   legend: {
      enabled: true,
      align: 'center',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      floating: true,
      x: 0,
      y: 40
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    series: [{
        data: growthData,
        name: "EPS growth"
    }],

  });
  var my1Button = chartY.renderer.button('1 Yr.',450,58,my1Callback, {
       zIndex: 7
    }).attr({
       align: 'right',
    }).add();
    var my3Button = chartY.renderer.button('3 Yr.',510,58,my13Callback, {
       zIndex: 7
    }).attr({
       align: 'right',
    }).add();
    var myAllButton = chartY.renderer.button('All',548,58,myAllCallback, {
       zIndex: 7
    }).attr({
       align: 'right',
    }).add();
   var i = 1;
   function my1Callback()
   {
      //chartY.xAxis[0].setExtremes(,);
     chartY.series[0].setData([4.51,9.36,11.67,24.12],false, {duration: 200, easing: 'easein'});
         //  chartY.series[0].data[0].update(200 );

    chartY.xAxis[0].setCategories([1388898000000,1396670400000,1404532800000,1412481600000]);
      chartY.redraw( ); 


   }
   function my13Callback()
   {
      //chartY.xAxis[0].setExtremes(,);
       chartY.series[0].setData([62.32,53.71,25.78,7.55,-1.51,-9.32,-10.14,-3.76,4.51,9.36,11.67,24.12],false, {duration: 200, easing: 'easein'});
     chartY.xAxis[0].setCategories([1325739600000,1333598400000,1341460800000,1349409600000,1357362000000,1365134400000,1372996800000,1380945600000,1388898000000,1396670400000,1404532800000,1412481600000]);
       //  chartY.series[0].data[0].update(200 );
     chartY.redraw( ); 

   }
   function myAllCallback()
   {
      //chartY.xAxis[0].setExtremes();
     chartY.series[0].setData(growthData,false, {duration: 200, easing: 'easein'});
     chartY.xAxis[0].setCategories(averageLabel);
      //   chartY.series[0].data[0].update(200 );


   }

});
```

Each button as show in jsfiddle reseting yAsix & xAsis but  animation is missing as compare the way it is loading default(very first time when graph is loading)
I have tried some method ( the code is in given jsfiddle link) but its not very smooth please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initial animation for any series is different from any others. During first animation, clipping rect is animated, not series itself. So solution is to use `remove()` and `addSeries()` instead of using `setData()`:

```
function my13Callback() {
    chartY.series[0].remove(false);
    chartY.xAxis[0].setCategories([1325739600000, 1333598400000, 1341460800000, 1349409600000, 1357362000000, 1365134400000, 1372996800000, 1380945600000, 1388898000000, 1396670400000, 1404532800000, 1412481600000], false);
    chartY.addSeries({
        data: [Math.random() * 100, 53.71, 25.78, 7.55, -1.51, -9.32, -10.14, -3.76, 4.51, 9.36, 11.67, 24.12],
        name: "EPS growth"
    }, true, {
        duration: 200   
    });
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eszwd420/7/

Note: It looks like working properly in 4.0.4, while 4.1 is kind of broken..

Comment: working fine, just an issue on each button click the point on drawn line is changing from solid round to square/triangle, i want the point solid round always

Comment: Then set for series [marker](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.marker)  - symbol.

Comment: Thank you- Marker is fine, a last issue http://jsfiddle.net/eszwd420/ the last label "NEXT YR"  is missing somehow, If i set the width of graph all the labels are fine and visible but with width the responsive of graph is missing. Please suggest how can able set all passed labels

Comment: Most probably there isn't enough space for rendering all labels so some of them are hidden.

Comment: i am giving chart width but then image is not responsive, can you please help me how can manage both- i mean, width + resposive chart

Comment: If you want responsive chart, then you can't set fixed width - that's clear, I hope ;) What would you like to achieve? When you have small chart (let's say.. 200px200px), then you can display big number of categories, because these won't fit.

Comment: yes, i am clear on fixed width, I have solved the issue some how, added autoRotation: [-40, -60, -90] for now..i dont know it this break in furture when i will have long data range